# SP 2016 performance: spucworkerprocessproxy excessive SQL queries

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sandbox-solution, performance, sql-query

A recent run of performance counters on our SP 2016 on prem installation showed a very high value for `sharepoint foundation(spucworkerprocessproxy)\executing sql queries` -- *think millions!* Subsequent perf counter runs show this number always present and never changing.

My research has suggested that `spucworkerprocessproxy` is a process related to Sandboxed code. How do I identify sandboxed code running in our Sharepoint site? Are workflows created in Sharepoint Designer sandboxed? Would disabling the Sandboxed code feature disable these workflows?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the [sandboxed solutions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ff872402(v%3Doffice.14)) that have been installed in each Site Collection via its [Solution Gallery](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ff872402(v%3Doffice.14)#using-site-collection-tools).

SharePoint Designer workflows are not packaged solutions (sandboxed or otherwise), unless they have been exported from Designer in one environment and imported via Solution Gallery in another environment.  Most likely sandboxed solutions are either a third-party purchased solution or something custom-developed in-house.